# Mathematica : Conditional Operations on Lists

Tags: loops, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

I would like to average across "Rows" in a column. That is rows that have the same value in another column.

For example :

```
e= {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 
   {69, 7, 30, 38, 16, 70, 97, 50, 97, 31, 81, 96, 60, 52, 35, 6, 
    24, 65, 76, 100}}
```

[image]

I would like to average all the Value in the second column that have the same value in the first one.

So Here : The Average for Col 1 = 1 & Col 1 = 2

And then create a third column with the result of this operation. So the values in that columns should be the same for the first 10 lines an next 10.

Many Thanks for any help you could provide !

LA

Output Ideal Format :

[image]

Comment: I believe you have an error in your code: `d[[10 ;; 20]]` should be `d[[11 ;; 20]]`

Comment: Thank You ! I am sorry, i must do sthing wrong but none of yours or Belisarius Proposition produce the same output as above :(

Comment: Just to be sure, you are not regenerating the random numbers between trials, are you?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard : Sorry did not see this last Comment. I copied all the comments & code I needed, You can remove anything you think is not necessary. Thank You again !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting problem.  This is the first thing that came into my mind:

```
e[[All, {1}]] /. Reap[Sow[#2, #] & @@@ e, _, # -> Mean@#2 &][[2]];

ArrayFlatten[{{e, %}}] // TableForm
```

To get rounding you may simply add `Round@` before `Mean` in the code above:  `Round@Mean@#2`

Here is a slightly faster method, but I actually prefer the `Sow`/`Reap` one above:

```
#[[1, 1]] -> Round@Mean@#[[All, 2]] & /@ GatherBy[e, First];

ArrayFlatten[{{e, e[[All, {1}]] /. %}}] // TableForm
```

If you have many different elements in the first column, either of the solutions above can be made faster by applying [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html) to the rule list that is produced, before the replacement (`/.`) is done.  This command tells Mathematica to build and use an optimized internal format for the rules list.

Here is a variant that is slower, but I like it enough to share anyway:

```
Module[{q},
  Reap[{#, Sow[#2,#], q@#} & @@@ e, _, (q@# = Mean@#2) &][[1]]
]
```

---

Also, general tips, you can replace:

`Table[RandomInteger[{1, 100}], {20}]` with `RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 20]`

and `Join[{c}, {d}] // Transpose` with `Transpose[{c, d}]`.

Comment: @500, if you need to clarify your question, edit it, rather than posting examples in the comments.

Comment: Should this be self-explaining? Tried it and it works. Compact code. But I don't really get it. - Think when coding on the poor soul that has to maintain it, one day.

Comment: @ndroock1 I admit to writing opaque code, but it's not really complicated.  In fact, it's pretty straight forward, once you're familiar with `Sow` and `Reap`.  Basically, `Sow[x, t]` stores item `x` in a bin called `t`, then `Reap` gathers all the bins, and (with a third argument) does something with each one of them.  In my first method, that something is `# -> Mean@#2 &` which breaks down as make a rule for `#` (the tag name) into `Mean@#2` (the mean of the contents of the bin).  After that, it's just applying this rule to a copy of the first column, and appending it to the table.

Comment: @Mr.Wizzard : I am struggling to adapt your first code above on a bigger table : How can I make it to compute the average of the 5thcolumns values on a range of it based on the second column for example ? As of now it is the second based on the first column. I get the Snow[5#,#] for the column on which the average must be computed but can`t find how to modify the column number on wish the range is to be defined. I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: @500 if I understand, then you would need to change `e[[All, {1}]]` to `e[[All, {2}]]` and `Sow[#2, #]` to `Sow[#5, #2]`.  If you are doing this on a large table, adding `Dispatch` (`... /. Dispatch@Reap ...`) will be important.  Also, Leonid gave a faster solution you should look at.  Since you apparently want a function that is generalized for arbitrary "index" and "average" columns, I will write one later, and add it to my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Works perfectly now ! I did work through Leonid`s one which works perfectly as well. As a beginner, learning through the different solutions on actual problems I am facing is truly a gift !

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am addressing both of you, and I thought that the author of the question *and* the author of the answer both always get the comment to their inbox - isn't that so?

Comment: @Leonid, first point, I am always interested in seeing your methods, but this is not my question, and I also do not have mma8 to run it, so I'll leave that to 500.  Second point, I am fairly certain that I do not get a notice for every comment to every answer to each of my questions.  That would be a lot of notices!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, makes sense on both points. Will repost the comment as you suggest.

Comment: @500 I was able to squeeze another factor of 2 in speed with a somewhat longer solution compiled to C (still limited to relatively small keys (less than a million say), returns machine-precision numbers, not rationals. Requires M8), but did not post it. If that is of interest, I can edit my post to add that one.

Comment: @Leonid Curious to see ! I often work at home on a laptop with weak CPU..,

Comment: @500 Fine, I added the mentioned solution to my post, enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

What the heck, I'll join the party. Here is my version:

```
Flatten/@Flatten[Thread/@Transpose@{#,Mean/@#[[All,All,2]]}&@GatherBy[e,First],1]
```

Should be fast enough I guess.

**EDIT**

In response to the critique of @Mr.Wizard (my first solution was reordering the list), and to explore a bit the high-performance corner of the problem, here are 2 alternative solutions:

```
getMeans[e_] := 
Module[{temp = ConstantArray[0, Max[#[[All, 1, 1]]]]},
  temp[[#[[All, 1, 1]]]] = Mean /@ #[[All, All, 2]];
  List /@ temp[[e[[All, 1]]]]] &[GatherBy[e, First]];

getMeansSparse[e_] := 
Module[{temp = SparseArray[{Max[#[[All, 1, 1]]] -> 0}]},
  temp[[#[[All, 1, 1]]]] = Mean /@ #[[All, All, 2]];
  List /@ Normal@temp[[e[[All, 1]]]]] &[GatherBy[e, First]];
```

The first one is the fastest, trading memory for speed, and can be applied when keys are all integers, *and* your maximal "key" value (2 in your example) is not too large. The second solution is free from the latter limitation, but is slower. Here is a large list of pairs:

```
In[303]:= 
tst = RandomSample[#, Length[#]] &@
   Flatten[Map[Thread[{#, RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 300]}] &, 
      RandomSample[Range[1000], 500]], 1];

In[310]:= Length[tst]

Out[310]= 150000

In[311]:= tst[[;; 10]]

Out[311]= {{947, 52}, {597, 81}, {508, 20}, {891, 81}, {414, 47}, 
{849, 45}, {659, 69}, {841, 29}, {700, 98}, {858, 35}}
```

The keys can be from 1 to 1000 here, 500 of them, and there are 300 random numbers for each key. Now, some benchmarks:

```
In[314]:= (res0 = getMeans[tst]); // Timing

Out[314]= {0.109, Null}

In[317]:= (res1 = getMeansSparse[tst]); // Timing

Out[317]= {0.219, Null}

In[318]:= (res2 =  tst[[All, {1}]] /. 
 Reap[Sow[#2, #] & @@@ tst, _, # -> Mean@#2 &][[2]]); // Timing

Out[318]= {5.687, Null}

In[319]:= (res3 = tst[[All, {1}]] /. 
 Dispatch[
  Reap[Sow[#2, #] & @@@ tst, _, # -> Mean@#2 &][[2]]]); // Timing

Out[319]= {0.391, Null}

In[320]:= res0 === res1 === res2 === res3

Out[320]= True
```

We can see that the `getMeans` is the fastest here, `getMeansSparse` the second fastest, and the solution of @Mr.Wizard is somewhat slower, but only when we use `Dispatch`, otherwise it is much slower. Mine and @Mr.Wizard's solutions (with Dispatch) are similar in spirit, the speed difference is due to (sparse) array indexing being more efficient than hash look-up. Of course, all this matters only when your list is really large.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a version of `getMeans` which uses `Compile` with a C target and returns numerical values (rather than rationals). It is about twice faster than `getMeans`, and the fastest of my solutions.

```
getMeansComp = 
 Compile[{{e, _Integer, 2}},
   Module[{keys = e[[All, 1]], values = e[[All, 2]], sums = {0.} ,
      lengths = {0}, , i = 1, means = {0.} , max = 0, key = -1 , 
      len = Length[e]},
    max = Max[keys];
    sums = Table[0., {max}];
    lengths = Table[0, {max}];
    means = sums;
    Do[key = keys[[i]];
      sums[[key]] += values[[i]];
      lengths[[key]]++, {i, len}];
    means = sums/(lengths + (1 - Unitize[lengths]));
    means[[keys]]], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

getMeansC[e_] := List /@ getMeansComp[e];
```

The code `1 - Unitize[lengths]` protects against division by zero for unused keys. We need every number in a separate sublist, so we should call `getMeansC`, not `getMeansComp` directly. Here are some measurements:

```
In[180]:= (res1 = getMeans[tst]); // Timing

Out[180]= {0.11, Null}

In[181]:= (res2 = getMeansC[tst]); // Timing

Out[181]= {0.062, Null}

In[182]:= N@res1 == res2

Out[182]= True
```

This can probably be considered a heavily optimized numerical solution. The fact that the fully general, brief and beautiful solution of @Mr.Wizard is only about 6-8 times slower speaks very well for the latter general concise solution, so, unless you want to squeeze every microsecond out of it, I'd stick with @Mr.Wizard's one (with `Dispatch`). But it's important to know how to optimize code, and also to what degree it can be optimized (what can you expect).

Comment: Your code reorders the list.  Perhaps that is not a problem, but I avoided it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard True. Your method is very cool, but I'd additionally wrap the rules in `Dispatch`, or its performance will degrade with a (very) large number of different "keys".

Comment: I was concerned my code was already complicated enough, but that is certainly a valid point.

Comment: By the way, I take "very cool" coming from you as a high complement.

Comment: Is there any way to attach a file for me to show that it is note working on my notebook ?

Comment: @500 Thanks. To produce 3 columns, just apply `TableForm` to the answer I gave: `TableForm[myAnswer]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it's cool because it has the necessary (IMO) ingredients for coolness: obscure (non-obvious), beautiful, terse, and functional (in the general sense of the word) - +1.

Comment: @500 Strange, works for me: `{20,3}`. Have no idea why the difference.

Comment: Had to Transpose e ! Now Works !

Comment: @500 Ok, great. I used your initial definition of `e`. You apparently transposed it further down the page.

Comment: Thank You for those precisions Leonid !

Comment: @500 You are welcome! It is easy to lose performance in Mathematica, so it is often a good thing to ask yourself how a given piece of code will perform under a heavy load. Unless of course, you know in advance that performance is not critical in that particular case.

Comment: @Leonid thanks again for the  EDIT2 I have now to go through it and make it work !

Answer (score 3):

A naive approach could be:

```
Table[
  Join[ i, {Select[Mean /@ SplitBy[e, First], First@# == First@i &][[1, 2]]}]
, {i, e}] // TableForm

(*
1   59  297/5
1   72  297/5
1   90  297/5
1   63  297/5
1   77  297/5
1   98  297/5
1   3   297/5
1   99  297/5
1   28  297/5
1   5   297/5
2   87  127/2
2   80  127/2
2   29  127/2
2   70  127/2
2   83  127/2
2   75  127/2
2   68  127/2
2   65  127/2
2   1   127/2
2   77  127/2
*)
```

You could also create your original list by using for example:

```
e = Array[{Ceiling[#/10], RandomInteger[{1, 100}]} &, {20}]
```

**Edit**

Answering @Mr.'s comments

If the list is not sorted by its first element, you can do:

```
Table[Join[
  i, {Select[
     Mean /@ SplitBy[SortBy[e, First], First], First@# == First@i &][[1,2]]}],
{i, e}] //TableForm
```

But this is not necessary in your example

Comment: You guys are spectacular. I am new to Mathematica, and your help is really precious !

Comment: belisarius, I am getting funny results using your code.  Let `e = {{3, 77}, {3, 34}, {1, 57}, {2, 90}, {2, 21}, {2, 36}, {1, 34}}` then the mean for type `1` should be `(57 + 34)/2` not `57`.

Comment: @Mr. It assumes an ordered list (by its first element) as input

Comment: I do not see that in the specification.

Answer (score 2):

Why not pile on?

I thought this was the most straightforward/easy-to-read answer, though not necessarily the fastest. But it's really amazing how many ways you can think of a problem like this in Mathematica.

Mr. Wizard's is obviously very cool as others have pointed out.

@Nasser, your solution doesn't generalize to n-classes, although it easily could be modified to do so.

```
meanbygroup[table_] := Join @@ Table[
   Module[
     {sublistmean},
     sublistmean = Mean[sublist[[All, 2]]];
     Table[Append[item, sublistmean], {item, sublist}]
   ]
   , {sublist, GatherBy[table, #[[1]] &]}
       ]
(* On this dataset: *) 
meanbygroup[e]
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, the answers here are so advanced and cool looking, Need more time to learn them.

Here is my answer, I am still matrix/vector/Matlab'ish guy in recovery and transition, so my solution is not functional like the experts solution here, I look at data as matrices and vectors (easier for me than looking at them as lists of lists etc...) so here it is

---

```
sizeOfList=10; (*given from the problem, along with e vector*)
m1 = Mean[e[[1;;sizeOfList,2]]];
m2 = Mean[e[[sizeOfList+1;;2 sizeOfList,2]]];
r  = {Flatten[{a,b}], d , Flatten[{Table[m1,{sizeOfList}],Table[m2,{sizeOfList}]}]} //Transpose;

MatrixForm[r]
```

---

Clearly not as a good a solution as the functional ones.

Ok, I will go now and hide away from the functional programmers :)

--Nasser

Comment: your contribution is appreciated

Comment: We wish you good luck on your recovery/transition. It's worth the effort, I assure you. Just don't hesitate to ask for help posting questions as you make progress